# Vscode shows linting problems from node_modules folder in Problems tab

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

This happened after I disabled all my extensions, and restarted vscode, but as far as I remember the default ignored folder settings should be used to exclude the folder from showing up in the Problems tab. The only other thing that did change in-between was some removing and reinstalling of modules, but I don't see how that should change the ignore settings whatsoever.

[image: Problems tab showing node_module problems]

I don't see the `node_modules` folder in the explorer pane, and I assume vscode should use the same settings as the ignored settings.

I have it ignored in tsconfig: `"exclude": ["node_modules"],`
I have this in .eslintignore: `**/node_modules`

There is an option to 'hide excluded files' but it will still show the total count badge, and I would have to re-enable it everytime vscode starts.

The last option I can think of is that there's some different or newer typescript version somewhere down the module tree, because the errors are 99% about missing comma's and semicolons, and a few about expected Property or Signature?:
[image: index.d.ts file]

(I do expect that when I would remove and reinstall vscode this problem might disappear in typical Microsoft fashion, but I need a solution, not a workaround)